# Purpose of colon in url

Tags: reactjs, web

I was just looking at hbo max and noticed it had some colons in the url as such https://play.hbomax.com/page/urn:hbo:page:home. Do the colons have any significance or are they just used as a separator between values?

Comment: Ask HBO. Seems like use as a separator *would* have significance--and seems like it's a separator. But could just be a flat key. Who knows. URL handling is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

`urn` stands for Uniform Resource Name, a schema for organizing and namespacing unique identifiers. That's why the URL has colons in it and starts with `urn`, it's part of the specification. The colons themselves are just delimiters like you guessed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name